# Can't connect to my personal Ubuntu server with SSH outside LAN

Tags: networking, ssh

This is my first time setting up a server and I got a problem. When I try to connect to my server with SSH inside LAN, everything works fine but when I'm not at home and I try to connect to it, this happens :

```
C:\Users\MY_USERNAME>ssh -vvv MY_USERNAME@MY_DDNS_ADDRESS
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/MY_USERNAME/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "MY_DDNS_ADDRESS" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to MY_DDNS_ADDRESS [MY_IP_ADDRESS] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:000001FB2C4C0400
debug1: connect to address MY_IP_ADDRESS port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host MY_DDNS_ADDRESS port 22: Connection refused
```

I don't understand why the connection is refused. Here is what I already did :

- Forward port 22 traffic to my server in my router settings
- Allowing port 22 traffic in UFW on my server
- Try to connect to my server from different locations

Does anybody know what's the problem ?

Comment: M$error 10061 means tcp port not open... Check you port forwarding, firewall settings and server configuration

Comment: Ask your provider if they assigned you a personal external static ip address.

Comment: I am using a DDNS address synced with my modem, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: Have exactly same problem running ssh on Ubuntu 20.04: local ssh sessions work fine but external connections gets error 10001. Now, when you mention "different port in my router", was the ssh server configured on port 22 while external access was with some other port number as the router would forward such port to local server listening on port 22?

Comment: Yes, that’s it. The problem seemed to be that my router didn’t accept traffic on port 22 coming from the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by using a different external port in my router settings (instead of port 22). I don't understand what was the problem before, but it works now !